# How to get Java reflect to spot fields in the super class? not just the actual class

Tags: java, oop, reflection, audit

I've recently changed my schema a bit so my classes inherit from a super class, problem is my comparison method which generates an audit log, using Java reflect, is now only looping through the fields of the child class, not the superclass, is there a way to get all the FIELDS? or do I need to cast it into the super class.....?

Heres my method below:

```
public static <T> String GenerateChangeLogForEntity(T old, T updated) {
        String text = "";
        try {
            Field[] fields = old.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            if(fields != null) {
                BaseController.getLogger().info("Z1 num fields:"+fields.length);
                for (Field field : fields) {
                    if(field.isAnnotationPresent(Column.class)) {
                        String fieldName = field.getName();
                        BaseController.getLogger().info(field.getName());
                        if(field.isAnnotationPresent(Variation.class)) {
                            Variation v = field.getAnnotation(Variation.class);
                            fieldName = v.friendlyName();
                        }
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        if(field.get(old) != null && field.get(updated) != null) {
                            if(!(field.get(old)).equals(field.get(updated))) {
                                text += "<p><span class=\"field-name\">"+fieldName+"</span> changed from: <strong>"+GetFriendlyFieldValueForChangeLog(field.get(old))+"</strong>  to: <strong>"+GetFriendlyFieldValueForChangeLog(field.get(updated)) + "</strong></p>";
                            }
                        }
                        if(field.get(old) == null && field.get(updated) != null) {
                            text += "<p><span class=\"field-name\">"+fieldName+"</span> changed from: <strong>empty</strong> to: <strong>"+GetFriendlyFieldValueForChangeLog(field.get(updated)) + "</strong></p>";
                        }
                        if(field.get(old) != null && field.get(updated) == null) {
                            text += "<p><span class=\"field-name\">"+fieldName+"</span> changed from: <strong>"+GetFriendlyFieldValueForChangeLog(field.get(updated))+"</strong> to <strong>empty</strong>" + "</p>";
                        }
                        field.setAccessible(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {}
        return text;
    }
```

Comment: N.B: You probably shouldn't set `field.setAccessible(false)` to prevent race conditions in multi-threaded environments...

Comment: your means is: `instance.getClass().getSuperCLass().getDeclaredFields()`?

Comment: Thanks MJM, thanks everyone, yip that did it easy as pie! :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use `this.getClass().getSuperClass()` until this `getSuperClass()` method returns null to get the parent fields.

So, the best would be that you factorize your code. Implement one method that takes a list of `Field` as parameter and do your logical part within it, and a main method that search for fields through a `while(superClass != null)` loop.

Comment: watch for the getFilds() method, in my case it does not work for the superclass. I was only successful with the getDeclaredFilds()

Answer (score 18):

Though it's late, I'm adding my suggestion since it's a nice solution.

 
 
Spring framework provide a nice Util class 
`org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils` this class has several methods which we can use.
To get a Field instance of an attribute from objectClass and superClasses I used `ReflectionUtils.findField(clazz, fieldName);` 
 
Good thing with util is it doesn't throw an exception. Instead it returns null for invalid ones, so you can handle it gracefully.

Answer (score 9):

Apache Commons Lang provides a method [FieldUtils.getAllFields()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html) which is an implementation of @sp00m's algorithm.